# 32Gb Nexus 7 conversion to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Tried to install Ubuntu as per your instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation. It appeared to install and re-booted its self. However all that appeared was some very small text and there it stayed.

Eventually I re-installed the stock android, as per your instructions, which worked fine.

I chose the 32Gb option during the install. Any ideas as to what I can do?

Comment: This *sounds* like a bug, which would be *off-topic* on Ask Ubuntu and should instead be on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7)

Comment: Since this is a bug can you follow the progress here?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1079729  We are working on it.

Comment: Actually, how long did you wait?  It should say something like "Unpacking rootfs" and that part can take 10-15 minutes.  Perhaps you didn't wait long enough? If instead you dropped to an initramfs prompt, that's the bug above.

Comment: What version (how recently updated) is your installer? Does your **Nexus-7 32GB** device also have **3G** capability, or is it **WiFi**-only?

Comment: Got my nexus 7 32Gb+3G on Wednesday and downloaded all software on Thursday. You are correct it dropped to the initramfs prompt.